# Use for loop with two variable

Tags: bash, variables, loops, for-loop, awk

I have a question about for loop in Bash
I want to run awk command for specific range increasing by 34 but I don't know how to specify two variable in a for loop. 
I know how to do it for one variable but it is not working for two. 
this is my code for one variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in {1..3400..34}
do
printf "awk 'NR>=$a&&NR<=$b { if (/^[0-9]/) sum++} END {print "row\t", sum }' file "
done
```

but I want to specify both variables ($a,$b), something like this which is not working! :

```
for a in {1..3400..34} , for b in {35..3400..34}
do
printf "awk 'NR>=$a&&NR<=$b { if (/^[0-9]/) sum++} END {print "row\t", sum }' hydr_dE.txt && "
done
```

Thanks,

Comment: so what you wanted is just printing the awk codes with a, b expanded? or you want the awk codes to get executed?

Comment: My final aim is to execute the awk code for range between 1-3400 with that range which I couldn't find any solution. So I tried to print it out and run the output by using && in middle of each awk! but my first question is about adding two variable in a for loop. I am not sure if I should open another question or not?

Comment: can you make an example to explain what you want? very likely you were on a wrong way. you could use smaller `a` `b` and `step` to make the question simpler.

Comment: Sure! I have a file with 3400 rows. I want my script to: first divide the rows into 100 parts from 1-34 , 35-68 and so on. Then count the number of rows which contain numbers not character like in my awk { if (/^[0-9]/) sum++} and give me a tab delimited outputs from divided rows (1-100) and the counted numbers. Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: when I mentioned "examples" it means your input files expected outputs... of course, the simplified version from your real data.

Comment: Thanks @kent I have tried to type it in the comment but devnull answered it. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If you need to loop over two variables, you'd probably want to ensure that those contain the *same amount* of data.  `echo {1..3400..34}` would produce one value more than `echo {35..3400..34}`.

(2) Assuming that the two inputs are of the same size, you could use a `while` loop:

```
while read a b; do
  echo ": $a :: $b :";
  # do something with a and b here
done < <(paste <(seq 1 34 3400) <(seq 35 34 3434))
```

(You could use the loop with the two inputs of unequal size too, but that is probably what you don't want.  In the above example, the variable `a` would consume the longer input.)

The `<(command)` form is referred to as process substitution.

Answer (score 5):

Using C-style for loop:

```
for ((a=1,b=35;a<=3400,b<=3400;a+=34,b+=34)); do
    echo ": $a :: $b :"
done
```

(will have the same output as devnull's answer, but in pure Bash).

Of course, in this simple case, it's enough to just do:

```
for ((a=1;b=a+34,b<=3400;a+=34)); do
    echo ": $a :: $b :"
done
```

I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how to adapt this to what you exactly want.